# Configurar varias IP's

Tags: linux, ip

buenas.

Quiero configurar en una maquina ubuntu 2 IP's
192.168.1.6 y 192.168.11.45
mascara: 255.255.255.0
y quiero que la IP 192.168.1.6 salga por el gateway 192.168.1.87 y que la IP 192.168.11.45 salga por el gateway 192.168.11.87

esto para poder cambiar mi maquina de subred tendiendo 2 IP's estaticas

este el el netplan con el que intente realizar esto.

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s31f6:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.11.45/24
        - 192.168.1.6/24
      routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.11.87
          table: 100
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.1.87
          table: 101
      routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.11.45/32
          table: 100
        - from: 192.168.1.6/32
          table: 101
```

podrian ayudarme?